# Rest api return item without foreign key in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDxkT.png)

I created rest api with Spring-boot that return all data from database(MySql).
In sql many to one relationship Category-Item

In controller i want to get all item with foreign key

#### Entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String category_name;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Maqal> maqals;

    public Category() {

    }

    public Category(String category_name) {
        this.category_name = category_name;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "maqals")
public class Maqal implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String context;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", unique = true)
    private Category category;


    public Maqal() {
    }

    public Maqal(String context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

#### Controller

```java
    @RequestMapping("/allData")
    public Iterable<Maqal> getAllData() {
        return maqalsDao.findAll();
    }
```

But  /allData return without foreign key. How can I add proterties or values for foreign key in Maqals.class?

Comment: I can't comment so I will write here for the time being until I get details for this. Then I will write a valid answer instead.
Are you using Spring Data? Do you have any getters and setters in your classes?

Answer (score 0):

Given you are using Spring Data and your database is consistent with your entities, add getters and setters for all ID fields in both entity classes in order for ID to show up and be set.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show the data which one using foreign key. Suppose you need to show the values means to manually the data using the foreign key.

Otherwise:
  You need to remove the @JoinColumn annotation.